# How to customize apache logging to dump request only information

Tags: apache, http, request

We need to debug some apps and would like to dump extra logs in apache with only request info. We need request info before apache will do the redirect and process the response. Is it possible?

Comment: Look into module `log_forensic`.

Comment: good, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Np, I have put it as a more complete answer, you can accept it if it is good for your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more complete answer...

There are 2 modules that will help you.  log_forensic and unique_id.

unique_id: it associates a unique number to each received request, it is used by log_forensic.

log_forensic: it logs *before* and *after* processing a request, so each request == 2 lines in this log.  You cannot modify it like the regular logs, the format is fixed.  The only available directive is to specify where you want the log file to go.